# Try to use name manager as bar chart data but show error message

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is the screeshot and message

[image]

[image]

Anyone what is the problem?

ChartMonths `=OFFSET(Formula!$A$1,,,COUNTIF(Formula!$A$1:$A$100,”<>”))`

ChartValues `=OFFSET(Formula!$B$1,,,COUNTIF(Formula!$B$1:$B$100,”<>”))`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see worng is the `OFFSET` formula.

You are using `”` when you should be using `"`

Try these instead, should fix the problem:

```
=OFFSET(Formula!$A$1,,,COUNTIF(Formula!$A$1:$A$100,"<>")) 

=OFFSET(Formula!$B$1,,,COUNTIF(Formula!$B$1:$B$100,"<>"))
```

If these don't work I'd try:

`=OFFSET(Formula!$A$1,,,COUNTIF(Formula!$A$1:$A$100,"<>"&""))`

If your data were to use headers in A1:B1 (which data sets usually do) use the below to exclude:

`=OFFSET(Formula!$A$2,,,COUNTIF(Formula!$A$1:$A$100,"<>"&"")-1)`